# R - `reactive` after `observeEvent` in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny app that takes a `.csv`file as input and do some calculations and plot graphs.
the problem is, since the data input is reactive, places where i show my plots shows error till i upload a csv, as shown in image below.

[image: image showing error]
Here's the part of the code in my `server`, that shows error:

```
patient_type_data <- reactive({ 
--my code that subsets the data based on other 
})
```

`wait_data` is a reactive variable containing data from .csv uploaded.
I've tried to solve it like:

```
patient_type_data <- reactive({
observeEvent(wait_data(), --my code--) 
})
```

and

```
patient_type_data <- observeEvent(wait_data(),
reactive({--my code--})
)
```

both always returned some error at some point.
So, how do i not let the functions execute, as long as the .csv is not uploaded or solve this errors?

Comment: You probably need a req around subset `req(subset)` where it's missing on startup. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html and https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html

Comment: It was this previously:
`output_data <- subset(output_data, select = -c(critical_patients))`. after your comment, i made it this:
`output_data <- req(wait_data(), subset(output_data, select = -c(critical_patients)))`. the error doesn't show as long as the .csv is not uploaded, but the subsetting of data is not done at all. put simply, the thing that line of code was intended to do, is not happening at all. how do i fix ?

Comment: Please add a min reprex as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It's very difficult to test and give advice without seeing it.

Comment: ok, i'll edit the question with complete code. I wanted to keep my question, as concise as possible.

Comment: Still difficult to understand but what if you put a `req(wait_data())` right after `patient_type_data <- reactive({ `

Comment: sure, glad to help

Comment: You should try to avoid wrapping `observeEvent` with `reactive` and vice versa. Have a look at `?eventReactive()`.